# 1D array frequency counter for other methods

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted to call a method that would prompt the user to enter the miles driven, gallons used, calculate the miles per gallon, display how many miles per gallon this type of car got on this trip. I also wanted this method to passes back a “1” to add to the frequency counter for each type of car later on.  (If the car is a Honda, add a “1” to arrayname[1], if the car is a Toyota, add a “1” to arrayname[2], etc.).

```
     int[] mpgList = new int[5]; // 5 because there are 4 more car types
     mpgList[0] = 

    do{
        prompt = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter"
            + "\n"
            + "1 For Honda"));

        if (prompt == 1)
        {     
            forHonda();


        };
```

......

```
 public static void forHonda(){
    double miles, gallons, mpg;

    miles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Miles Driven "));
        if (miles <= -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input Is Negative"
                    + "\n"
                    + "Try Again");
        miles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Miles Driven ")); 
        }
    gallons = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Gallons Used "));
        if (gallons <= -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input Is Negative"
                    + "\n"
                    + "Try Again");
        gallons = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Gallons Used ")); 
        }
    mpg = (miles/gallons);
    if (gallons == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Division by Zero"
                + "\n"
                + "Try Again");
    miles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Miles Driven "));
    gallons = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Gallons Used "));
    mpg = (miles/gallons);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("MPG for HONDA: %.0f"
            + "\n", mpg));
```

......

```
    public static void counter(int x[]){
    for(int counter = 0; counter< x.length; counter++)
        x[counter]+=1;
}
```

this was kind of the idea i was going for, but I got stuck at how to utilize the array for the freq counter

Comment: So, when you add `forToyota()` are you going to repeat all the code currently in `forHonda()`?

Comment: Could you explain more detail? Where did you call `counter`?

Comment: i currently have it in multiple if (prompt ==1); if (prompt ==2) {1 being honda and 2 being toyota, and calling similar methods into those if's} i'll later change it to switch case @JimGarrison

Comment: for the counter, id want to call it whenever the user chooses a car type and counts which ever car type they chose and however many times.. if that makes sense. This is the part im mainly confused about; where to call it @ManhLe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use only arrays and primitive data types, but let's assume that is not a requirement (you're writing Java code after all). Here's how I would go for solving the problem of keeping track of fuel consumption of multiple car types.

So we have a pre-defined list of car types that need to be displayed and somehow accessed by some integer number. So let's create an Enum for that:

```
public enum CarType {

    HONDA(1, "Honda"), 
    TOYOTA(2, "Toyota"), 
    ALFA(3, "Alfa Romeo")
    // ...
    ;

    private int id = 0;
    private String displayName;

    public static CarType forId(int id) {
        for (CarType type : CarType.values()) {
            if (type.id == id) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No car type with number " + id);
    }

    private CarType(int id, String displayName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

You want to keep track of fuel consumption, possibly total number of miles driven, total distance traveled, number of trips and MPG:

```
public class Consumption {

    private double miles = 0;
    private double gallons = 0;
    private double mpg = 0;
    private int numberOfTrips = 0;

    public void addTrip(double miles, double gallons) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (miles > 0 && gallons > 0) {
            this.miles += miles;
            this.gallons += gallons;
            numberOfTrips++;
            mpg = this.miles / this.gallons;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both miles and gallons have to be greater than zero");
        }
    }

    public double getMiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public double getGallons() {
        return gallons;
    }

    public double getMpg() {
        return mpg;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTrips() {
        return numberOfTrips;
    }

}
```

You don't have to declare that you throw an `IllegalArgumentException` since that is a `RuntimeException`, but it's nice for the caller to know that this can happen and you can add a Javadoc block to describe, under which circumstances it does.

You want to be able to keep track of fuel consumption of multiple vehicle types:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ConsumptionManager {
    private HashMap<CarType, Consumption> data = new HashMap<>();

    public Consumption addTripData(CarType type, double miles, double gallons) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Car type cannot be null");
        }
        Consumption consumption = data.get(type);
        if (consumption == null) {
            consumption = new Consumption();
            data.put(type, consumption);
        }
        consumption.addTrip(miles, gallons);

        return consumption;
    }

    public Consumption getConsumption(CarType type) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Car type cannot be null");
        }
        return data.get(type);
    }

}
```

Now you can dynamically build your UI using the CarType Enum with something like this:

```
    for (CarType type : CarType.values()) {
        // build your UI, e.g. on the console something like:
        System.out.println(String.format("%d) %s", type.getId(), type.getDisplayName()));
    }
```

Then after collecting the type's id, miles and gallons used on the trip you add it and possibly display current state:

```
    // create instance of ConsumptionManager somewhere, possibly in your start-up code: 
    // ConsumptionManager mgr=new ConsumptionManager();
    try {
        Consumption consumption=mgr.addTripData(CarType.forId(id), miles, gallons);
        // display mpg/number of trips/etc, e.g. on the console
        System.out.println(String.format("Average range after %d trips: %f", consumption.getNumberOfTrips(),consumption.getMpg()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // display error to the user, e.g. on the console
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

All you have to do in order to add another car type is to add it to the CarType enum and you're done. You also don't have magic numbers like number of types you support, their respective IDs, etc all over your code, but only in the places that need to know about them.